# ¿Cómo se hacen las asignaciones en esta parte de código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buen día, el código que pongo a continuación está destinado a búsqueda binaria. Lo entiendo en su totalidad, menos el segundo renglón cuando dice

```
len (numeros) -1
```

Ese es un método destinado a saber la longitud de una lista, pero ¿a quién se lo asigna? ¿la variable 'izquierda' no tiene ningún tipo de asignación?

Aca dejo el código entero:

```
def busqueda_binaria (numeros, numero_buscado):
    izquierda, derecha = 0, len (numeros) - 1

    while izquierda <= derecha:
        mitad = (izquierda + derecha) // 2
        if numero_buscado == numeros[mitad]:
            return True
        elif numero_buscado > numeros[mitad]:
            izquierda = mitad + 1
        else:
            derecha = mitad - 1
```

Comment: Ya está respondida, pero solo añadir que aunque el interprete ignora el espacio blanco entre el nombre de la función y sus parámetros, si es cierto que por costumbre o convención se utiliza más la forma `len(numeros)`. Esto ayuda (en mi opinión) a visibilizar mejor el código puesto que se podría dar a entender que len y (numeros) son cosas separadas o que se te ha olvidado una " coma ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una asignación múltiple valiéndose de la técnica de desempacado, [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

En Python las estructuras de datos llamadas tuplas están delimitados por paréntesis, pero al momento de declararlas los paréntesis son opcionales. Así que si se declara una secuencia de valores "sueltos", Python los entiende como tupla.

```
>>> x = 2, 3, 4
>>> x
(2, 3, 4)
```

Si se asigna la estructura de datos a una cantidad de variables iguales a la cantidad de datos de esa estructura, entonces Python desempaca la estructura y le asigna cada elemento correspondientemente a las variables.

```
>>> y, z = 2, 3
>>> y
2
>>> z
3
>>> y, z = [6, len("ab")] # También funciona con listas
>>> z
2
```

Si se trata de asignar a un número diferente de variables que la de elementos en la estructura:

```
>>> a, b, c = 2, 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahí la marqué como resulta a la pregunta