# Me aparece el error: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Tags: python

Trato de resolver este sistema de EDOs y me aparece el error cannot unpack non-iterable float object y no sé como resolverlo

Esta es la función a integrar:

```
def sist(z, t, k, m):

    phi1, phi2, phi3, w1, w2, w3 = z

    w = k/m

    phi1_dot = w1 
    phi2_dot = w2
    phi2_dot = w3
    w1_dot = -w*(phi1 - phi2) - w*(phi1 - phi3) 
    w2_dot = -w*(phi2 - phi3) - w*(phi2 - phi1) 
    w3_dot = -w*(phi3 - phi1) - w*(phi3 - phi2) 
 
    return w1, w2, w3, w1_dot, w2_dot, w3_dot
```

Este es el método:

```
# MÉTODO DE RK4:

t0 = 0. 
tf = 50.
k = 1.
m = 1.

z = solve_ivp(sist, t_span=(t0,tf),  y0=[1., 1., 1., np.pi/40, np.pi/20, np.pi/10], method='RK45', 
args=(k, m), vectorized=False)
```

Comment: Parece que lo que estás pasando a `sist()` como `z` es un `float` y cuando intentas hacer `phi1, phi2, phi3, w1, w2, w3 = z` no puede desempaquetarlo.

Comment: Tal como dijeron, el problema es que estás tratando de desempacar una estructura en varias variables. Para asignar a múltiples variables un mismo valor es: `phi1 = phi2... = z`. [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/381766/80870) te puede ayudar a entender el unpacking

Answer (score -1):

Solución: Poner el sistema de ecuaciones en forma matricial, y tener en cuenta que al usar solve-ivp la función debe ser de la forma f(t ,y1, y2,...)

```
# Intervalo de tiempo:

t0 = 0. 
tf = 10.


# Sistema de ecuaciones:

def sist(t, s, k=1, m=1):

    w = k/m

    ds = np.dot(np.array([ [0,0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1], 
    [-2*w,w,w,0,0,0], [w,-2*w,w,0,0,0], [w,w,-2*w,0,0,0]]),s)

    return ds


# MÉTODO DE RK4:

# Número de pasos de tiempo:
n_RK4 = 200

# Tiempo:
t_eval = np.linspace(t0, tf, n_RK4)

# Solución al sistema de EDOs:
Sol_RK4 = solve_ivp(sist, t_span=(t0,tf),  y0=[1., 1., 1., np.pi/40, np.pi/20, 
np.pi/10], method='RK45', t_eval=t_eval)

phi1_RK4, phi2_RK4, phi3_RK4, w1_RK4, w2_RK4, w3_RK4, t_RK4 = Sol_RK4.y[0], 
Sol_RK4.y[1], Sol_RK4.y[2], Sol_RK4.y[3], Sol_RK4.y[4], Sol_RK4.y[5], Sol_RK4.t
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esta respuesta en Meta para entender por que tu respuesta recibió un voto negativo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2882#2882